# Connecting to Private AWS RDS Postgres using Java driver

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-rds

Wondering the best approach to trying to connect to a Private AWS RDS Postgres instance. For me to connect with pgAdmin Ihad to create an SSH tunnel to the DB. I would like to be able to connect to this DB instance via a Java app from my local box and from our EC2 instances. I think the EC2 instance side won't be hard since they are in the same VPC and I think the security groups can talk, but how do you go about doing a SSH tunnel for the Java drivers?

Or perhaps I am looking at this all incorrectly? BTW this is NOT a Spring application.

Tried to connect directly to the server with pgAdmin. That failed, even with my IP added to it's security group. This is because for security reasons (no public API to the DB server) it is a Private server.

Comment: I would not suggest having applications from outside the vpc talking directly to the db.  If this is for local dev, consider running a local postgres.

Comment: Normally that is exactly what we do. But this is to collect metrics on external API usage, and since we hit the APIs even from our development box, we need to track them.  That said I think I will create an API I can hit which will accomplish the same thing when in DEV mode.

Answer (score 0):

Will just create an API to update the DB when in DEV mode. Kind of an overkill but will keep things secure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).